# Powershell Script - SCCM - Desktop Refresh

Tags: powershell, script, sccm

We are currently doing a desktop refresh on our leased pcs.  Id like to see if its possible to add the computer to the same device collections it is replacing.

We have 5 x Patching Cycles and machines are divided spread across those device collections.  These are also separated so that we do not take down an entire department or site when patching.

Id like to create a powershell script that could be run after deployment of the replacement device to look up the old devices collections and add the new device to those collections.

Any pointers would be useful.

Cheers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is entirely within the list of possibilities, and it's not exactly high-level PowerShell, depending on how you go about it. So knowing what you've tried would help us better answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are PowerShell scripts available to find out the collection associated with a device
Get Computers in SCCM Collection -  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Computers-in-SCCM-948e666f

Once you have the list of collections then, you can use PS command-let for SCCM **Add-CMDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRule** to add machine into all required collections.

Comment: what is the problem with this answer?

Comment: It might be improved by inserting the code from the remote site in your answer here if the TechNet site contrnt licence allows it. As it stands the remote site may be removed or moved at which point there would be nothing here to say what actually needs to be done. Answers that rely heavily on external sites are often considered bad. Please read https://superuser.com/help/referencing for advice on how to write an answer requiring external content.

Comment: OK, got it. I'll take care of it. Now I can't post any answers and I have no clue why is that :(

Comment: Sadly it seems that due to the voting that went on you have hit one of out automated blocks. Improving your answers and getting upvotes may help, or it might clear in a day or so. New users are also slightly rate limited so it might be that. Welcome to the site!